application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) in case of app is not installed and launched from universal link
In a scenario where the user receives an email to install the app I want to pass some context from the link and receive it when the app is launched after installing the app from App Store. Would application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) method get called when the app is launched?
What is the best way to handle deferred deeplink?

Hey, did you find any solution?
